Ghostwriter preview style
How can I change the style used by the Ghostwriter cmark-gfm preview markdown flavor on Ubuntu variants? I hate that level 1 headings are rendered in all caps.
(I think this is on-topic here because it's a tool commonly used by programmers to write documentation.)
